# How to optimise route in google map using Google map client java api.

Tags: java, google-maps, routes, directions, google-directions-api

I am getting route details for list of latitude and longitudes like this,

```
DirectionsRoute[] routes = DirectionsApi.newRequest(context)
                .mode(TravelMode).origin(startPoint).destination(endPoint)
                .waypoints(wayPoints).await();
```

But the routes that i am getting are not optimised so i want to optimise route by using google java client api.

In google map javascript api we can optimise by giving boolean attribute like this

```
 {
  origin: LatLng | String | google.maps.Place,
  destination: LatLng | String | google.maps.Place,
  travelMode: TravelMode,
  drivingOptions: DrivingOptions,
  waypoints[]: DirectionsWaypoint,
  optimizeWaypoints: boolean
}
```

But how to achieve this using Google maps java client api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `optimizeWaypoints` method. Make sure that you use the latest (0.1.16) version of google-maps-services:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.16'
}

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.16</version>
</dependency>
```

In your code:

```
DirectionsRoute[] routes = DirectionsApi.newRequest(context)
    .mode(TravelMode)
    .origin(startPoint)
    .destination(endPoint)
    .waypoints(wayPoints)
    .optimizeWaypoints(true) // Add this
    .await();
```

Comment: Thanks its helpful but whether this method is available in google map services version 0.1.1